# use a return value from a function to assign to a string

Tags: php

I am using PHP regex and fopen in a function (remote_filesize()) to get the size of a file, remotely (fopen, pre_match, implode). The outcome, or file size, is echoed using the function callback: `remote_filsize($filename)` where $filename is the URL gotten from a MySQL PDO query using index of $row['alerts']. Alerts is the actual filesize that is checked when the program window is opened and runs the above function.

How can I use the return function value to compare the next indexed row from my table as a comparison value... if the value from row[alerts] is more than row[status] ->the old value which I manually saved to database from the last time I checked the records page. Ultimately, I want to use the result of less than to highlight the field in my "records page" to have a green background or red background (class="danger or success") depending on size change, of course.

This is what I used but it always returns "green" success when the value of the new filesize is greater than the value of the old filesize. In fact the class for my table data field is always green background regardless of the values compared state.

```
<td class="overflow">
<?//php 
/**
 * gets files size to compare then compares size 
 * of saved value @status to current callback value @alerts
 */
if( !empty($row['alerts'])) {
$filename = $row['alerts'];
$oldfilesize = $row['status'];
if( remote_filesize($filename) > $oldfilesize ) { $highlite = "danger"; } else { $highlite = "success"; }
echo "<a href='' title='$filename'>url</a>";
echo  remote_filesize($filename);
} 
//?></td>
            <td class="<?php echo escape( $highlite ); ?>"><?php echo escape($row['status']); ?></td>

id     alert     status 
------------------------
1   |  55000  |  55010 
------------------------
```

the above results table would tell me that the background of 'status' should be red since the size is greater than the 'alert' value integer. All I am checking for is if file has been altered (size has changed).

Comment: Instead of using fopen and regex, you should use cURL, make a HEAD request to the remote file  and take a look at the info you get from `curl_getinfo` (it contains the e.g. size). Instead of doing that twice, you should only do this once and save it into a variable and use that variable for comparison. If the if statement does not execute as expected, `var_dump` both variables and take a look at what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly this is one of those late night should-of-had-some-coffee situations. I solved this by simply checking to see if the two values where the same, or not. `if( remote_filesize($filename) == $newfilesize )` then make the result default to green for success if the values are the same. this is a more encompassing solution seeing that a file size could be less than the saved value and still constitute that the file has "changed" regardless of if the change was larger or smaller.